# What is "method's object" and "class's object"?

Tags: object, methods

I was reading oracle docs.

> 'When a thread invokes a synchronized method, it automatically acquires the intrinsic lock for that method's object and releases it when the method returns.'

here they have mentioned "method's" object.

What exactly is Method's object?

And now here they are mentioning object associated with clas

> 'the thread acquires the intrinsic lock for the Class object associated with the class.'

Then what is Class object associated with class?

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the *method's object are the methods that are non-static*, that is to say, the method that are specific to the instance.

While the *class methods are the static methods* declared in the class. Depending on the language that can be like global functions

```
MyClass myInstance = new MyClass();

// Method's object:
// Specific to the instance and won't be called by separate threads at he same time for myInstance, but can be called on another instance of MyClass
myInstance.method();

// Class method:
// Is at the class level, won't be called by separate threads at the same time at all.
MyClass.myStaticMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

Class is just a user's custom data type, representing some methods and variables.

Object is instance variable of that Class, like a blueprint.

And there also Class methods and Object methods.

You send an object method to a particular instance of that class, and Class method to that Class.

For example, you have Class Car. And it just describes how the car is constructed and what it can do.Then, it may have methods `Create a new car`. So you'll have few objects than, Mercedes and Audi, for example. And this objects can respond to methods drive and stop. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

An object is an instantiated entity which can be manipulated or accessed.

Answer (score 0):

A method's object, is the object the method is currently being used for.

Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. 
Every class has Object as a superclass.(don't get confused by this)
All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class.